# How to import a .csv file with a specific words in the file name in R?

Tags: r, csv

Thanks for reading this post. I import a .csv file from Qualtrics platform almost daily to a specific folder (i.e., "Thesis_Folder"). Whenever I import a .csv file to the Thesis_Folder, the default name of the .csv file includes today's date and time. In other words, the name of the .csv file changes every time I import the data from Qualtrics (e.g., "Thesis data June+3_2019++12:48"). However, the .csv file always contains the words "Thesis data". My question is: How can I import a .csv file if the file contains "Thesis data" in the name of the file?

list.files() lists the name of the files with specific patterns, but it does not import them as data frames. Thank you.

Comment: CSV files ... [`read.csv`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.0/topics/read.table)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
files <- list.files("C:/Users/User/Desktop/csv", pattern=".*Thesis.*\\.csv$", full.names=TRUE)
list_of_frames <- lapply(files, read.csv)
```

Store all data.frames in a list.

Comment: (1) `list.files(..., pattern=".*Thesis.*\\.csv$")`, skip the `grepl`. (2) Should probably include `list.files(..., full.names=TRUE)`, otherwise you will not be able to find them when in a dir other than current directory. (3) `assign` workflow is inefficient, suggest `list_of_frames <- lapply(files, read.csv)` (or `fread`). If you're going to do the same or very-similar thing to many frames, keeping them as individual variables is inefficient.

Comment: (4) If you must use a `for` loop, I recommend `seq_along(files)` or `seq_len(length(files))` instead of `1:length(files)`. Why? When your list of files is empty (`character(0)`) for some reason, `for (i in 1:0)` will run twice instead of the expected zero times (see for yourself: `1:length(character(0))`).

Comment: Works well,thank you a lot, both@DSGym and @r2evans. I just added this short code to get it stored as a data frame:

Thesis_Data = as.data.frame(list_of_frames[[1]])

Comment: you do not need the `as.data.frame` there. You data is already stored as data.frame

Comment: @Identicon, by doing `as.data.frame(list_of_frames[[1]])`, you are discarding everything except the first file of data, is that really what you want? Nothing in your question suggested you needed to work on all data together, so we assumed to keep them separate. If you want them all combined into one frame, then `alldata <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(list_of_frames, list(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))`.

Comment: Thank you for the note, @r2evans. All I had needed was to import the .csv data file that contains the word "Thesis data" in its name, which I was able to do with your and DSGym assistance. All I have is only one data file, not multiple data files.

Comment: Okay, I didn't get that out of the question. Okay, then instead of using `lapply` (which can return multiple frames), you might want to alarm if you find multiple files. I know it makes no sense now to do so, but in a month or ten months after you haven't looked at this stuff in a while, it makes a little more sense to raise a flag (at least a `warning`) if your assumptions are not meant. Declarative code and specificity will help the "future you" troubleshoot an unreproducible thesis workflow (I know, I learned the hard way on my grad thesis).

Answer (score 0):

Untested since you do not provide example data, but this should work:

```
library("rio")
library("dplyr")
data <- list.files( # find respective files
  path = "./Thesis_Folder",
  pattern = ".csv$", # you might want a more specific regex if possible
  full.names = TRUE
) %>% 
  lapply(import) %>% # import from rio usually works well
  bind_rows() # bind the list of data.frames to one big df
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help,@JBGruber . Unfortunately, this code does not work, it imports empty dataframe object. Also, I'm unsure if this can do do it since this code does not include the specific words (Thesis data).

Comment: As I wrote above, you might want to change the pattern to get only the files you really want. If all files really start with "Thesis data", you might want something like `"Thesis data.+.csv$"` instead. I tested this now and the code itself works.